# Bootstrap markdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router, markdown

Hey guys I am trying to use this: http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/ 
. I am using the Ionic framework and working on a single page web application.
This are the includes in the header of my index.html:

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- JQuery animated scrolling plugin -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<!-- MARKDOWN --> 

<link href="css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/vendor/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>     
<script src="js/vendor/he.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/to-markdown.js"></script>
```

Currently, I am running this example from the website:

```
<form>
<input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
<textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input name="publish" type="checkbox"> Publish
</label>
<hr/>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

Unfortunately, the outcome is nothing like the example. I just see a blank form that is not even close to the expected output.
I have also tried the includes(first 4 lines) from this example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/99r9D . However, I am still having no luck. Can anyone who has experience with this bootstrap plugin help me out?

This is what I see:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below snippet. Its working for me, 
`Submit` button may not work here because of permission issue. , 
Added some extra style to show the checkbox properly.

```css
.checkbox {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.10.0/js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.10.0/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" class="form-control" />
  <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input name="publish" type="checkbox">Publish
  </label>
  <hr/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form
```

Comment: Hey Arun, unfortunately, this is not working for me.

Comment: @Ayudh just check is there any error in console ? (right click--> inspect element-->console )

Comment: @Ayudh Just copy and paste everything from the snippet and check whether it working or not

Comment: That is exactly what I did, that is when I took the picture but the outcome was the same as my initial attempt

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it works with preview.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.10.0/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f9b4728164.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/js/to-markdown.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/js/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.10.0/js/bootstrap-markdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>



<form>    
    <textarea id="myEditor" name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10">
    </textarea>
</form>
```